# Gnome Tweak Tool editable via bash/python?

Tags: bash, python, gconf, gnome-tweak-tool

Is there a way to access the variables to edit via bash (or other libraries with bash or python)? Similar to how you can use 'gconftool-2' in bash to edit properties that would update them after edited.

For example, I would like to run a script to disable 'the file manager to handle the desktop' by terminal (bash or python) instead of opening this window each time.

I also have tried making 'show_desktop' to false in nautilus in gconf-editor but that doesn't do anything.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and compiz as the window manager on Gnome (2 I believe, or whatever comes with 11.10).

Answer (score 1):

We're going to use Gio to get the Base Key (the category the value is at). Once we get that value we're going to set a CheckBox on it to change the value. We then setup various signals to listen for changes in the setting and CheckBox. I know it's not the desktop one but you can plug it into the BASE_KEY. By the way, you shouldn't try and use GConf in GNOME 3, because it's been deprecated.

```
from gi.repository import Gio, Gtk

class GSettingsTest(object):
    BASE_KEY = "org.gnome.nautilus.preferences"
    def __init__(self):
        # Make a check button to change the value.
        settings = Gio.Settings(self.BASE_KEY)
        change_check = Gtk.CheckButton("Always Use Browser")
        change_check.set_active (settings.get_boolean("always-use-browser"))
        settings.connect("changed::always-use-browser", self.on_changed, change_check)
        change_check.connect('toggled', self.on_check_clicked, settings)

        window = Gtk.Window(type = Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_title("Change Nautilus")
        window.set_border_width(24)
        window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        window.add(change_check)
        window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_changed(self, settings, key, change_check):
        change_check.set_active(settings.get_boolean("always-use-browser"))

    def on_check_clicked(self, button, settings):
        settings.set_boolean("always-use-browser", button.get_active())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = GSettingsTest()
```

[image: What the program looks like, with the settings synced.]

Comment: Actually you did lead me to it. The actual key is 'show-desktop-icons'. Access it from 'org.gnome.desktop.background' -> show-desktop-icons. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No Problem:) Glad I could help